# Implementing an any container

Tags: c++, templates, boost-variant, boost-any

I'm well aware of `boost::any` and `boost::variant`, but in this instance they don't fit my needs.

Normally, to contain an object of unknown type, one would derive it from a common base and access the instance through virtual methods. But, what can one do if it's impossible to use a common base?

I know that in this example you would have to know the contained type, but bear with me. `std::vector` is a template class with top level class also being a template. As far as I know it cannot be given a non-template base without modifying the STL headers. Now, lets say I want to create a vector of a single type but the containing class doesn't care about the type, but it does require access to some of the 'common' methods, `size()` and `pop_back()` for example.

Using `boost::any`, the type has been erased, making it almost impossible to dereference the contained object. `boost::variant` and `tuple` require knowing before hand what types may be inserted, causing the containing class to itself be a template.

What I have so far is something like this:

```
struct container
{
    virtual ~container() = 0;
    virtual void pop_back() = 0;
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
    ...
}
template < typename T >
struct contained
{
    std::vector< T > _vec;
    contained ( size_t n, T _what ) : _vec( n, _what ) {}
    virtual void pop_back() { _vec.pop_back(); }
    ...
}
class some_class
{
    container* _cont;
    template < typename T >
    void create ( T _first ) { _cont = new contained< T >(1,_first); }
    ...
}
```

Here the client can call on `create()` and the template parameter should be determined automatically. Not a great example I know, but I'm trying to hide the template parameters from the client. Without doing this, `some_class` would have to also keep track of what type is being stored.

My method relies on virtual calls which causes a performance loss, especially when the internal class has virtual methods of it's own.

Are there any other types of containers that would better suit my needs?

Ideally, I'd like something like this

```
container = std::vector< T >;
container.pop_back();
container.push_back( T2 ); // compile error if types don't match
```

Where internally it would track the type and do a simple cast rather than rely on virtual methods. Almost like `auto` with the difference being that once declared it's type can change.

Edit:

In reality, I want to create a wrapper around `std::basic_filebuf`. This wrapper class opens the file with `char`,`wchar_t` or `unsigned long` based on the BOM. The wrapper is also derived from `basic_filebuf` with the template parameter being whatever the client chooses. Internally, it converts unicode code points from the file to the clients desired encoding. The problem arises when storing the internal `basic_filebuf` because it can be declared with any type as the template parameter. I don't want to use template specialization because I want the client to be able to pass in their own `basic_filebuf` instance.

Must be VS2010 compatible, which has limited features from C++11.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve where you need to do this?

Comment: @GManNickG One example would be the standard stream classes where the element type could be `char` `wchar_t` `int`... How would you store that template without caring about the internal type? How about `std::string` and `std::wstring`? Almost identical but require slightly different handling.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I mean what is your program going to eventually *do*?

Comment: @GManNickG Does it matter what my program is trying to do? I've clearly described what I want and what I've tried. I'm looking for alternate way to store any type without loss of type information.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand your description either. There's this paragraph "Ideally, I'd like..." which would be a perfect place for an example of how you intend to use the container. If I'm guessing right though, what you want is impossible: Consider that the first line (the one that defines the underlying type) is made dependent on a runtime parameter. In that case, the third line (the one that could mismatch) can not possibly cause a compile-time error.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt OK, Edited the question to also state how I intend to use this.

Comment: Are you aware of the codecvt facets? FWIW, for a similar approach (sensing the encoding and then using the according input method) I simply used a function that looked at the first few bytes and returned a stream that was configured accordingly. That said, unless you are doing something else that is terribly expensive, the overhead of any virtual function call will be dwarfed by the overhead of doing IO, the latter is still several magnitudes slower than a little indirection.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Looking at the BOM and creating a suitable stream is exactly what I'm doing. I've also added a phase that will translate the files encoding to whatever the client wants to use. The purpose of the desired class is to hold these streams. I'm looking at creating a modified variant, but I'll leave that until main part of code is complete, then I can see if there is any performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be combined with compile-time type checking.  Based on your "ideally" example:

```
container c;
if (thingKnownAtRunTime()) {
  c = vector<int>;
} else {
  c = vector<string>;
}
c.push_back("hello world");
```

For the filebuf case, though, you might get good enough with something like (warning: untested)

```
template<typename FILEBUF>
void gensputc(FILEBUF* fb, long long c) {
  FILEBUf::char_type c2 = smart_convert<FILEBUf::char_type>(c);
  fb->sputc(c2);
}

class FileBufWrapper {
public:
  template<typename FILEBUF> FileBufWrapper(FILEBUF* fb) {
    fb_ = fb;
    sputc_ = gensputc<FILEBUF>;
  }
  void sputc(long long c) {
    sputc_(fb_,c);
  }
private:
  typedef void(*sputc_t)(void*, long long);
  sputc_t sputc_;
  void* fb_;
};
```

The smart_convert function throws a runtime exception if the value cannot be converted to the char type.  Also, this needs to be done for every function you intend to call.

If you have access to c++11's std::function and std::bind, this can be made a little cleaner, especially for the cases where you don't need to convert anything.